# Multi-Column Composite Key Mapping with Hibernate and JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, composite-key

I have been trying for a few days now to get the composite key to work looking at the many example on the web, but still am missing something since it isn't working.

In the code below FMX.modelRiskMitigant and FMX.modelFacility are being correctly set, but hibernate is trying to set null in DB columns!

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FACILITY_MITIGANT_XREF")
@IdClass(FMXPK.class)
public class FMX implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="FACILITY_ID")
private Long facilityId;

@Id
@Column(name="RISK_MITIGANT_ID")
private Long riskMitigantId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="FACILITY_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Facility modelFacility;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="RISK_MITIGANT_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private RiskMitigant modelRiskMitigant;

}


public class FMXPK implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long facilityId;

private Long riskMitigantId;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="MODEL_FACILITY")
public class Fac implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="modelFacility", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<FMX> facilityMitigantXrefs;

 } 


@Entity
@Table(name="MODEL_RISK_MITIGANT")
public class RiskMitigant implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="modelRiskMitigant", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<FMX> facilityMitigantXrefs;

}
```

Comment: Resolved this issue by removing facilityId and riskMitigantId from FMX. Mapped Id field directly to facility and rismitigant objects.